# Bash: Date/Time math problems

Tags: bash, shell-script, date-time

The following script takes two inputs, `sourceFile="${1}"` and `trimFile="${2}"`. The `$sourceFile` is a video file that is to be trimmed into multiple new files based on data in the `$trimFile`. The `$trimFile` is a text file of the following structure (actual file related to this problem):

```
00:49:30,00:53:00 DescriptionA
03:33:30,03:38:40 DescriptionB
04:54:32,04:55:37 DescriptionC
```

The `$trimFile` uses both commas and spaces as delimiters in the script below. While rather obvious, each line represents a clip to be created from the `$sourceFile`. Further, the first field is the starting time of the clip to be trimmed, the second field is the ending time of the clip to be trimmed and the last field is a description of the clip.

My problem isn't with the trimming of the `$sourceFile`. I am trying to rename the new clips with a date and time relative to the original video files date. Each `$sourceFile` and `$trimFile` is named like the following example (which are the actual file names I am presently using): `2017-05-15_14-17-22 (2017-05-16 00-45-41.151674100 -0400) (HEVC27).mp4` and `2017-05-15_14-17-22 (2017-05-16 00-45-41.151674100 -0400) (HEVC27).txt`, respectively. Again, while rather obvious, the date components are `Year: 2017`, `Month: 05`, `Day: 16`, `Hour: 14`, `Minute: 17`, and `Second:22` (ignore the date is the parenthesis as it is an old reference with the wrong UTC adjusted date).

It should be evident in the script below how the date/time in the file is extracted as well as how the date/time within the `$trimFile` are extracted. To illustrate the problem, I need to show it both with and without certain lines commented out. Here it is with certain lines commented out (it will make sense as I discuss it next).

```
01: sourceFile="${1}"
02: trimFile="${2}"
03: 
04: IFS=$'\n'
05: 
06: dos2unix "$trimFile"
07: numberOfSegments=`cat "$trimFile" | wc -l`
08: numberOfSegments=$((numberOfSegments + 1))
09: extension=`echo "$sourceFile" | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'`
10: 
11: base=`echo "$sourceFile" | sed -e "s|.$extension||g"`
12: 
13: #~/bin/ffmpeg -i "${sourceFile}" -c:v copy "/dev/shm/$base.${extension}"
14: #sourceFile="/dev/shm/$base.${extension}"
15: 
16: # File date/time information
17: origYear="${sourceFile:0:4}"
18: origMonth="${sourceFile:5:2}"
19: origDay="${sourceFile:8:2}"
20: origHour="${sourceFile:11:2}"
21: origMinute="${sourceFile:14:2}"
22: origSecond="${sourceFile:17:2}"
23: 
24: origDate="${origYear}-${origMonth}-${origDay} ${origHour}:${origMinute}:${origSecond}"
25: 
26: for (( i=1;i<="$numberOfSegments";i++ ))
27:     do
28: 
29:         lineEntry=`cat "$trimFile" | head -"$i" | tail -1`
30: 
31:         startHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $1}'`
32:         startMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $2}'`
33:         startSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $3}'`
34: 
35:         endHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $4}'`
36:         endMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $5}'`
37:         endSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $6}'`
38: 
39:         description=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $7}'`
40: 
41:         beginSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($startHour*3600+$startMinute*60+$startSecond)}"`
42:         stopSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($endHour*3600+$endMinute*60+$endSecond)}"`
43:         duration=`awk "BEGIN {print $stopSeconds-$beginSeconds}"`
44: 
45:         newDate=$(date -d "@$(( $(date -d "${origDate}" +%s) + ${beginSeconds}))" +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
46: 
47:         new="${newDate}_${description}"
48:         echo "${lineEntry}"
49:         echo "${origDate}"
50:         echo "${beginSeconds}"
51:         echo "${new}"
52:         echo ""
53:         
54:         #~/bin/ffmpeg -n -vsync drop -fflags +genpts -i "$sourceFile" -ss "$beginSeconds" -t "$duration" -c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset slow "$new.mkv"
55: 
56: 
57:     done
58:     
59: #rm "/dev/shm/${base}.${extension}"
```

When I execute the script in this form, I get the following output corresponding to lines 48-52 in the script:

```
01: 00:49:30,00:53:00 DescriptionA
02: 2017-05-15 14:17:22
03: 2970
04: 2017-05-15_15-06-52_DescriptionA
05: 
06: 03:33:30,03:38:40 DescriptionB
07: 2017-05-15 14:17:22
08: 12810
09: 2017-05-15_17-50-52_DescriptionB
10: 
11: 04:54:32,04:55:37 DescriptionC
12: 2017-05-15 14:17:22
13: 17672
14: 2017-05-15_19-11-54_DescriptionC
15: 
16: 04:54:32,04:55:37 DescriptionC
17: 2017-05-15 14:17:22
18: 17672
19: 2017-05-15_19-11-54_DescriptionC
```

As you can see, the expected new date/time is output correctly in lines 4,9,14 (I am unsure why the last line of the `$trimFile` is output twice but that isn't my concern at the moment).

The problem lies is the actual renaming of the file when I remove the commented lines (lines 13, 14, 54, 59) from the script so that the script now looks like this:

```
01: sourceFile="${1}"
02: trimFile="${2}"
03: 
04: IFS=$'\n'
05: 
06: dos2unix "$trimFile"
07: numberOfSegments=`cat "$trimFile" | wc -l`
08: numberOfSegments=$((numberOfSegments + 1))
09: extension=`echo "$sourceFile" | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'`
10: 
11: base=`echo "$sourceFile" | sed -e "s|.$extension||g"`
12: 
13: ~/bin/ffmpeg -i "${sourceFile}" -c:v copy "/dev/shm/$base.${extension}"
14: sourceFile="/dev/shm/$base.${extension}"
15: 
16: # File date/time information
17: origYear="${sourceFile:0:4}"
18: origMonth="${sourceFile:5:2}"
19: origDay="${sourceFile:8:2}"
20: origHour="${sourceFile:11:2}"
21: origMinute="${sourceFile:14:2}"
22: origSecond="${sourceFile:17:2}"
23: 
24: origDate="${origYear}-${origMonth}-${origDay} ${origHour}:${origMinute}:${origSecond}"
25: 
26: for (( i=1;i<="$numberOfSegments";i++ ))
27:     do
28: 
29:         lineEntry=`cat "$trimFile" | head -"$i" | tail -1`
30: 
31:         startHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $1}'`
32:         startMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $2}'`
33:         startSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $3}'`
34: 
35:         endHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $4}'`
36:         endMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $5}'`
37:         endSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:,]' '{print $6}'`
38: 
39:         description=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $7}'`
40: 
41:         beginSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($startHour*3600+$startMinute*60+$startSecond)}"`
42:         stopSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($endHour*3600+$endMinute*60+$endSecond)}"`
43:         duration=`awk "BEGIN {print $stopSeconds-$beginSeconds}"`
44: 
45:         newDate=$(date -d "@$(( $(date -d "${origDate}" +%s) + ${beginSeconds}))" +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
46: 
47:         new="${newDate}_${description}"
48:         echo "${lineEntry}"
49:         echo "${origDate}"
50:         echo "${beginSeconds}"
51:         echo "${new}"
52:         echo ""
53:         
54:         ~/bin/ffmpeg -n -vsync drop -fflags +genpts -i "$sourceFile" -ss "$beginSeconds" -t "$duration" -c:v libx265 -crf 27 -preset slow "$new.mkv"
55: 
56: 
57:     done
58:     
59: rm "/dev/shm/${base}.${extension}"
60: 
61:
```

The files created by the script are named as follows:

```
1969-12-31_19-49-30_DescriptionA.mkv
1969-12-31_22-33-30_DescriptionB.mkv
1969-12-31_23-54-32_DescriptionC.mkv
```

Obviously, the dates used to name the file isn't anything like the output to stout created when I didn't re-encode the video but rather just tested that the new date variables were being calculated correctly.

So, my question boils down to this, why is, after doing some date/time math, the date/time correct when echoed to stout but grossly wrong when used to name the files once encoded.

Thanks!

Comment: "I am unsure why the last line of the `$trimFile` is output twice" – Because of `numberOfSegments=$((numberOfSegments + 1))` and then `i<="$numberOfSegments"`. If the operator is `<=` then you shouldn't increase. If you choose to increase then use `<`. Fixed code will also properly handle the edge case where original `numberOfSegments` is `0`. The whole loop can *probably* be rewritten as `while IFS=':, ' read -r …; do …; done < "$trimFile"`, without these inelegant `echo … | awk …` fragments.

Comment: The question is not minimal in terms of [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but it's complete, well formatted (including the code) and quite clear. For this effort +1 from me. The code itself can be improved (mainly by using the shell to read and manipulate strings). Although sub-optimal, IMO the code is not fundamentally flawed. Consider [sticking to `$()`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/612322/the-old-ticks-vs-parens-issue-confused/612337#).

Comment: @Kamil, thanks for this feedback. I am not sure why the `numberOfSegments=$((numberOfSegments + 1))` might have originally included the `+1` but it works once removed.  I will review and work to improve mcve ... it is a "bad" habit as I am someone who always personally wants more rather than less information; but, I see how it is problematic in help forums such as this and concise is better. Again, feedback that makes me better both in coding and contributing going forward is always appreciated. I will use your suggestions to experiment and see if I can make the overall project better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why is, after doing some date/time math, the date/time correct when echoed to stout but grossly wrong when used to name the files once encoded?

By uncommenting

```
sourceFile="/dev/shm/$base.${extension}"
```

you made the lines that follow extract wrong fragments.

```
origYear="${sourceFile:0:4}"
origMonth="${sourceFile:5:2}"
…
```

E.g. now `$origYear` expands to `/dev`.

I would expect `date -d` to throw errors similar to `date: invalid date '/dev-sh-/2 17:05:15'`. Maybe your `date -d` doesn't validate its input (or did you ignore the errors?).

You can fix this particular problem by assigning substrings to `origYear`, `origMonth` etc. before you change the value of `sourceFile`.

Comment: thanks! I added the `/dev/shm...` to make the process quicker but foolishly continued to reference the CLI inputted file name (which I just realized would also fail if happen to reference the sourceFile anywhere except its root directory. Again, thanks for unearthing my foolishness.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone references this post in the future, below is the corrected, working script. There were additional errors beyond what was addressed in this post that were also corrected (namely, the ffmpeg command and location of `-ss` and `-t` within the command.

```
01: sourceFile="${1}"
02: trimFile="${2}"
03: 
04: IFS=$'\n'
05: 
06: dos2unix "$trimFile"
07: numberOfSegments=`cat "$trimFile" | wc -l`
08: numberOfSegments=$((numberOfSegments))
09: extension=`echo "$sourceFile" | awk -F'.' '{print $NF}'`
10: 
11: base=`echo "$sourceFile" | sed -e "s|.$extension||g"`
12: 
13: ~/bin/ffmpeg -i "${sourceFile}" -c:v copy "/dev/shm/$base.mkv"
14: sourceFile="/dev/shm/$base.mkv"
15: 
16: # File date/time information
17: origYear="${sourceFile:9:4}"
18: origMonth="${sourceFile:14:2}"
19: origDay="${sourceFile:17:2}"
20: origHour="${sourceFile:20:2}"
21: origMinute="${sourceFile:23:2}"
22: origSecond="${sourceFile:26:2}"
23: 
24: origDate="${origYear}-${origMonth}-${origDay} ${origHour}:${origMinute}:${origSecond}"
25: 
26: for (( i=1;i<="$numberOfSegments";i++ ))
27:     do
28: 
29:         lineEntry=`cat "$trimFile" | head -"$i" | tail -1`
30: 
31:         startHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $1}'`
32:         startMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $2}'`
33:         startSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $3}'`
34: 
35:         endHour=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $4}'`
36:         endMinute=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $5}'`
37:         endSecond=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $6}'`
38: 
39:         description=`echo "$lineEntry" | awk -F'[:, ]' '{print $7}'`
40: 
41:         beginSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($startHour*3600+$startMinute*60+$startSecond)}"`
42:         stopSeconds=`awk "BEGIN {print ($endHour*3600+$endMinute*60+$endSecond)}"`
43:         duration=`awk "BEGIN {print $stopSeconds-$beginSeconds}"`
44: 
45:         newDate=$(date -d "@$(( $(date -d "${origDate}" +%s) + ${beginSeconds}))" +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S')
46:         newDate=`echo ${newDate}`
47:         
48:         new="${newDate}_${description}"
49:         
50:         ~/bin/ffmpeg -n -ss "$beginSeconds" -t "$duration" -i "$sourceFile" -c:v copy "$new.mkv"
51: 
52:     done
53:     
54: rm "/dev/shm/${base}.mkv"
```